# How to go through the data of a table using a where clause

Tags: t-sql, loops

I have the following database and query:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    (`group` int, `points` int)
;

INSERT INTO table1
    (`group`, `points`)
VALUES
    (1, 115),
    (2, 125),
    (1, 105),
    (2, 000),
    (3, 005),
    (1, 020),
    (2, 005),
    (1, 010),
    (2, 005),
    (3, 030),
    (2, 000),
    (2, 055),
    (2, 100),
    (1, 020),
    (3, 055),
    (3, 055),
    (1, 005),
    (1, 010),
    (2, 025),
    (1, 035),
    (2, 100),
    (1, 120),
    (3, 140),
    (3, 105),
    (1, 065),
    (3, 025),
    (4, 015),
    (1, 005),
    (2, 010),
    (1, 130),
    (4, 040),
    (1, 055),
    (4, 020),
    (4, 060),
    (3, 010),
    (3, 105),
    (4, 125),
    (3, 000),
    (2, 005),
    (2, 010),
    (1, 115)
;

CREATE TABLE soruce1
    (`group` int)
;

INSERT INTO soruce1
    (`group`)
VALUES
    (1),
    (2),
    (3),
    (4)
;

  select s1.`group`, SUM(t1.`points`) FROM table1 as t1
    inner join soruce1 as s1
      on s1.`group` = t1.`group`
  where s1.`group` = 1
  GROUP BY s1.`group`
  ORDER BY SUM(t1.`points`) ASC;
```

[Database and Query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77428/4) (SQL Fiddle Link)

How can I loop through all of the values in source1 with the where clause without having to use a While Loop so when it finishes running the query for group 1 it'll then move onto group 2 and so on until the end of the table, naturally, the select will be used in an Insert

This is just a sample of the data, source1 has almost 5000 entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove that where clause and the query will aggregate the sum for each group.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56e60/1/0)

```
 select s1.[group], SUM(t1.points) FROM table1 as t1
    inner join soruce1 as s1
      on s1.[group] = t1.[group]
  --where s1.[group] = 1
  GROUP BY s1.[group]
  ORDER BY SUM(t1.points) ASC;
```

Comment: *facepalm* and i've been slaving away trying to get it to work when the answer was so simple, the query was done by someone else on my team and i had to edited it so that the search wasn't hard coded, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Comment out the WHERE line `--  where s1.group = 1` and you'll get 4 rows? Is that what you mean?

Comment: yeh, though the original query is more complex but it's doing the exact same thing, can't believe the answer was so simple, must be a performance problem i'm having